# IF statement using date field from database

Tags: php

I have a working insert within PDO statements but I'm trying to add an if statement around it for a date check as well as existing records.

If I run it just to check for existing records, like so:

```
$dealerSkuCheck = "
    SELECT 
        sku_id,
        dealer_id,
        expire_date
    FROM placements_new p
        INNER JOIN skus s
            ON p.sku_id = s.id
    WHERE p.dealer_id = :DEALER
        AND   s.frame = :FRAME
        AND   s.cover1 = :COVER
        AND   s.color1 = :COLOR
        AND   p.order_num = :INVOICE
";


while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $values = [
        ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
        ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
        ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
        ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],
        ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
        ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
        ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
    ];

    $values2 = [
        ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
        ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
        ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
        ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
        ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],

    ];

    try{
        $checkExisting = $MysqlConn->prepare($dealerSkuCheck);
        $existingRslt = $checkExisting->execute($values2);
        $count3 = $checkExisting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            while($row3 = $checkExisting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $expiration[] = $row3['expire_date'];
            }

    }catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }
    //print_r($count3);


    // IF records do not exist, or records exist and today is after expiration date
    if(empty($count3) ){
        for($i=0; $i<$row2["QUANTITY"]; $i++) {

            try{
                $insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($insertPlacement);
                $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. It matches records that exist and bypasses them, and inserts any that don't exist, just as I expect it to.

However, When I add the date check to the if statement like so:

```
 if(empty($count3) || strtotime($expiration) < strtotime('now')
```

It doesn't work and I get `strtotime() expects param 1 to be string, array given`

This is obviously because I'm storing `expire_date` in an array but I can't seem to work out how to modify this to read the date properly.

Again, everything else works but I just want my if statement to say `if the record doesn't exist OR if it exists but today is after the expire_date of that record, then perform the following insert`.

I'm obviously doing something wrong with reading that date but I'm lost on what exactly.

Comment: So why is `$expiration` an array?  Are you really getting multiple rows from that fetch?  If so, how do you know which row is important?

Comment: This runs at the end of the day and I'm averaging anywhere from5 to 25 of those array records a day. It's for purchased items that are regularly updated, but in the event that they were purchased after a certain time, we just create new records

Comment: @downvoter if someone is downvoting my question, can the at least explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$expiration` is an array.  If you're adding the conditional within the inner while loop, you'll want to reference the expire date directly from the query results:

```
if (empty($count3) || strtotime($row3['expire_date']) < strtotime('now'))
```

Comment: This bypassed the error, fortunately, however it still inserts all of the matches even though there are only 20 with an older expiration date that should be updated. So it's grabbing all matched rows successfully, but it seems to be disregaring the date clause

Comment: question: since $count3 is fetching an associative array, and I'm checking that for the initial matches, could I use the data value from that and it would be more accurate?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! Thank you so much, that cleared it up